# how to hold dialogbox when check textbox is not empty in dialog box

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am opening a dialog box in a winform the problem is that at dialog box i have a textbox where i am checking if the user has filled information or not. Below is the code that opens the dialog box

```
frmRescheduleNotes _scAttempt = new frmRescheduleNotes(_rdate, _rtime, BttnText, ModelType, _UserName, eventId, EventTextid, _OrderId, delDate);
    DialogResult dr = _scAttempt.ShowDialog(this);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {

    }
       else
    {

       DataSet _dt = _commonDAC.GetOrderDetailByOrderIdEventTypeId(_OrderId, 3);
       dataGridReschedule.DataSource = _dt.Tables[0];
       dataGridReschedule.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

       naviBar1.ActiveBand = this.naviBand1;
    }
```

The problem is that I give a message to user if he did not fill any information in the textbox " Fill information in Textbox" but after this it return on main function .

```
if (txtNotes.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Notes");
        return;
    }

result = _commonDAC.SaveBuilderChanges(_date, _time, _eventId, _eventTextId, txtNotes.Text, User, _date, _OrderId, EventDetail.ToString());

if (result > 0)
    {
        int UpdateResule = _commonDAC.UpdateOrderDateTimeWithDeliveryBy(Convert.ToDateTime(_readyDate), Convert.ToDateTime(_readyTime), _OrderId, Convert.ToDateTime(_DeliverBy));

        this.Close();
    }
```

How do I check do that.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to close the dialog and return to the original function when the user does not enter something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell where the code that you posted resides (in the main form or in the dialog box), but typically, you would run your validation code when the user goes to submit the dialog box, and if the validation code fails (and you've informed the user as such), then you would simply not set a dialog result (OK or otherwise) and you would not close the dialog.  Thus, you're effectively cancelling the submission of the dialog box.